# Ben Noach give a non-religious ben Yisrael non-kosher food?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, noahidism, bnei-yisrael

If a ben Noach invites a non-religious ben Yisrael to his home for Torah study(let's say they study the seven laws of Noach together) and the ben Yisrael gets hungry, and he's going to not eat kosher food anyways, can or should the ben Noach offer him food from his non-kosher kitchen?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question depends on whether non-Jews have the obligation of לפני עיוור לא תתן מכשול (the prohibition of placing a stumbling block before the blind). I address this question in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56873/1713).

In summary, the prohibition of *lifnei iver*--even according to the more stringent opinion--only applies to non-Jews for halachot that they are obligated in. Since non-Jews are not obligated to keep kosher (except for the prohibition of *eiver min hachai*, but we can leave that aside for now), there is no halachic prohibition for a non-Jew to provide non-kosher food to a Jew.

As I mentioned in the linked answer, however, a Jew eating non-kosher food is definitely problematic from his perspective even if it is not from his host's perspective. As such, it certainly couldn't hurt for a non-Jewish host to go beyond the letter of the law and provide kosher food. It would prevent the Jew from sinning.

Answer (score 0):

Feed him fresh fruits and vegetables. Wash and inspect for insects. Kosher concerns solved.

Comment: Sure but that just avoids the question rather than answering it. What if he doesn't have any fresh fruit or vegetables?

Comment: Packaged food with a hechsher - ritz crackers. Are we seriously going to ad absurdum saying that a person has absolutely NOTHING to feed a guest and has to cook for them? Then go to the store and pick something up! Providing a methodology for solving the problem isn't "avoiding the question."

Comment: It doesn't have to get to that point, though. Maybe (as I mentioned in my answer) the host has no obligation whatsoever to do that.

Comment: @Daniel Interesting related side question - does hochei'ach tochi'ach apply in this case, especially since the ben Noach might very well be responsible for enabling the Jew to sin (lo tisa alav cheit)? That's not a question of lifnei iver at that point...